# Unable to get <M-Up> to work in insert mode

Tags: vimrc

I am using Vim version 8.0 and I would like to use `<M-Up>`, `<M-Down>`, `<M-Left>` and `<M-Right>` for navigating from window to window during insert mode. I am unable to get this work. These are the key-bindings in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <M-Left> <C-w><Left>
inoremap <M-Right> <C-w><Right>
inoremap <M-Up> <C-w><Up>
inoremap <M-Down> <C-w><Down>
```

In normal mode, things work. That is, when the key maps are changed from `inoremap` to `noremap`. Would someone have an idea how i can troubleshoot the problem or what is wrong in my above configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `:h i_CTRL-O`. From the help docs:

```
CTRL-O      execute one command, return to Insert mode
```

Try these:

```
inoremap <M-Left>  <C-O><C-w><Left>
inoremap <M-Right> <C-O><C-w><Right>
inoremap <M-Up>    <C-O><C-w><Up>
inoremap <M-Down>  <C-O><C-w><Down>
```